# How to print values present in <nobr> tag using selenium webdriver

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

it would be really helpful if someone could point out to me in the right direction. 
I am trying to print values which are present in nobr tag.

this is my code.

```
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;

public class appannieuserrating {
    public static WebDriver driver;
  @Test
  public void f() throws Exception{
      driver.findElement(By.id("login-button")).click();
         driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("sample.test@gmail.com");
         driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("password");
         driver.findElement(By.id("login_submit_button")).click();
         Thread.sleep(5000);
         driver.navigate().to("https://www.appannie.com/apps/ios/app/storage-hunters-uk-the-game/reviews/?date=2015-07-06~2015-07-06");
         Thread.sleep(5000);

         String s1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ngCellText.cell-inner.ng-scope")).findElement(By.tagName("img")).getAttribute("src");
         System.out.println(s1);

  }
  @BeforeTest
  public void beforeTest() {
      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.get("https://www.appannie.com/");
  }

  @AfterTest
  public void afterTest() {
  }

}



    <div class="ngCanvas" ng-style="canvasStyle()" style="height: 467px;">
<div class="ng-scope ngRow even" ng-row="" ng-class="row.alternatingRowClass()" ng-click="row.toggleSelected($event)" ng-repeat="row in renderedRows" ng-style="rowStyle(row)" style="top: 0px; height: 58px;">
<div class="ngCell col0 colt0" ng-class="{'sorted': col.sortDirection}" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" style="height: 58px;">
<div class="ngVerticalBar ngVerticalBarVisible" ng-class="{ ngVerticalBarVisible: !$last }" ng-style="{height: rowHeight}" style="height: 58px;"> </div>
<div ng-cell="">
<div class="ngCellText cell-inner ng-scope">
<span stars="row.getProperty(col.field)" aa-stars="">
<nobr>
<img alt="*" src="/media/pictures/star-whole.png">
<img alt="*" src="/media/pictures/star-whole.png">
<img alt="*" src="/media/pictures/star-whole.png">
<img alt="*" src="/media/pictures/star-whole.png">
<img alt="*" src="/media/pictures/star-whole.png">
</nobr>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here am trying to count the number of stars present in the "nobr" tag somehow its printing null value.

kindly point me in the right direction guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do smth like this:

```
 List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@aa-stars]/nobr")).findElements(By.tagName("img"));
 int counter = 0;

 for(WebElement we: elements) {
     if("*".equals(we.getAttribute("alt"))) {
         counter++;
     }
 }

 System.out.println(counter);
```

Unfortunately, your password is incorrect so I cannot try myself :D :D Tried locally with the same html - should work.

**UPD:**

I forgot to tell - in your attempt to find img element - you ignored the **nobr**. Yes. It is in DOM too. If  you want to find ANY next img - do like this:

```
.findElement(By.xpath("//img"));
```

If you use `by tagName` - it is assumed that you search for direct child.

**UPD 2**

If you rely on src and believe that this img should be a star, consider this:

```
 for(WebElement we: elements) {

     String text = we.getAttribute("src");
     if(text!=null) {
         if(text.contains("star"){
              counter++;
         }
     }
 }
```

**UPD 3**

```
        List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@aa-dtars]/nobr")).findElements(
            By.tagName("‌​img"));

    int counter = 0;

    String starPicLink = "/media/pictures/star-whole.png";
    for (WebElement we : elements) {
        String text = we.getAttribute("src");

        if (starPicLink.equals(text)) {
           counter++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(counter + " Star");
```

**UPD 4**

pastie.org/10292596#34 - working version

Comment: Hi... thanks for the reply... and it worked perfectly fine... but an we validate using the "src" as in the source code "/media/pictures/star-whole.png" if the url changes to "/media/pictures/star-blank.png" can the url be the validating point?

Comment: @user1856470 Updated the answer based on urls you provided.

Comment: sorry for the late reply... but i tried the code that you have given...
here is what i did.... 
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@aa-dtars]/nobr")).findElements(By.tagName("img"));
int counter = 0;
for(WebElement we: elements){
String text = we.getAttribute("src");
System.out.println(text);String s1=https://www.appannie.com/media/pictures/star-whole.png";       if(text==s1){
if(text.contains("https://www.appannie.com/media/pictures/star-whole.png")){counter++;
}else{
break; }}
System.out.println(counter+"Star");}

Comment: By the way, AVOID comparing strings with `==` Use `equals()`

Comment: well it sort of worked... 
it did count the star.. but if there were 5 stars... with the same url... its not updating the count...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82962/discussion-between-user1856470-and-teh-emprah).

Comment: Okay, UPD 3. Last time :D

Comment: hii... i tried the UDP 3 but still there is no use... i still dunno were am i going wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

I tried something link below to identify a input tag inside nobr tag:

xpath=//div[@id='div0_17']/span[@id='outer0_366']/nobr/input